How to change the default prefix of Spring @NestedConfigurationProperty in application.properties file?
Suppose I have a class Foo and this code:
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Config {
  @NestedConfigurationProperty Foo foo;
}

First of all I understand in order to use a class Foo like above that is not an inner class of Config, I MUST use @NestedConfigurationProperty. is that correct?
Next, I have to author application.properties like so:
foo.prop1=xxx
foo.prop2=xxx
...

If I use any other prefix except foo in application.properties, the parameter is not parsed properly. What I would like to do is be able to say:
bar.prop1=xxx
bar.prop2=xxx
...

How can I do this?

You can get your desired behavior without @NestedConfigurationProperty because looks like your properties are flat not the nested.
In case you want to do this without @NestedConfigurationProperty. You have to create another Bar POJO.
Below solution with @NestedConfigurationProperty
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Config {

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private final Property bar;

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private final Property foo;

    public Config(Property bar, Property foo) {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    
    // Getter and Setter
}

public class Property {
    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;

    public Property() {
    }
    //Getter and Setter
}

